# Custom database connections lost on upgrade in settings.xml

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

After upgrading between two versions of Invantive Control, my custom connections for Freshdesk together with Exact Online have disappeared from `settings.xml`.

Is there any way to recover the settings? They were quite complex.

Answer (score 1):

The connections from `settings.xml` are gone permanently. But with some luck you can find a backup in the folder `Backup` of the Invantive folder. Per loadable version it contains a backup file. You will find your settings there.

As an alternative, it is better to create an additional file in your Invantive folder named something like `settings-YOUR-NAME.xml`. All files matching `settings-*.xml` in that folder are merged into settings.xml upon application start.

And of course, always make sure you have a recent backup that works ;-)